# Trying to Echo a value from a select drop down in PHP

Tags: php, select, echo

I am in school for web development, so I clearly don't know a lot yet.  I am trying to grab a value from a select, and output it in a paragraph.  I know it's about the Browns, but everything else works, but I cannot seem to find anything on StackOverflow, or Google on how to grab the value that works.  I get the following error:

Notice: Undefined variable: draft in C:\wamp\www\lab 5\process.php on line 42

This error is in my paragraph, which makes me think I am grabbing the value, but it isn't outputting correctly?  I am using a variable to show where I want to output that value in the paragraph.

This is my HTML:

```
 <li><select id="uDraft"
            <select>
            <option value="Draft Offense">Draft Offense</value>
            <option value="Draft Defense">Draft Defense</value>
            <option value="Trade them, we can't pick good anyways">Trade them,  we can't pick good anyways</value>

        </select></li>
```

This is my process.php code:

```
if(isset($_GET["uDraft"])){
$draft= $_GET["uDraft"];
}
echo "I want to output **$draft var** as the value they choose so it shows                       the choice in a paragraph that is pre-written";
```

All of my other text boxes work, I just cannot seem to get the value from the select, so that I can show what it says in the text, into the paragraph.  I also had a select for wins, but gave up when I couldn't figure out how to grab the value.  I know I can use radio buttons, but I am trying to learn how to grab the value from the drop down.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: basic html <select id="uDraft" you forget name <select id="uDraft" name="uDraft" .... and make sure your form method is get when you use $_GET

Comment: This is some really bad HTML. You have two opening `select` tags and only 1 that closes. All of your option tags don't have closing tags. Replacle all `</value>` with `</option>` besides the select tag should have a name attribute. I'd recommend reading up on HTML before you continue with PHP.

Comment: I am sorry guys, the tags are closed, and form method is get.   I have a lot of stuff on the html, and php, I didn't want to copy the whole html/php code and have two large sets of code.  I just forgot to copy the close tags, but they are there.  as well as the closing </li> tag I don't have listed.  But I do see the missing option close tags, not sure why i put in </value> tags other then not paying attention.  Thank you.

Comment: @ScottF, I gave you a plus vote for your question. Students need to be treated better. Do the same for another student. Pay it forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your dropdown a **name**:

HTML:

```
<li>
   <select name="uDraft">
      <option value="Draft Offense">Draft Offense</option>
      <option value="Draft Defense">Draft Defense</option>
      <option value="Trade them, we can't pick good anyways">Trade them,  we can't pick good anyways</option>

   </select>
</li>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET["uDraft"])){
    $draft= $_GET["uDraft"];
    echo $draft;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Loko this fixed the issue.  Thank you for not lumping on about the bad html, while it was, I am sure everyone made stupid mistakes when they started out.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks again , didn't know I had to do that.  Best wishes to you.

Comment: @ScottF Good luck in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1st you have simple html errors, closing the select tag early, no name on select and closing the options tags incorrectly. It should be:

```
<select id="uDraft" name="uDraft">

    <option value="Draft Offense">Draft Offense</option>
    <option value="Draft Defense">Draft Defense</option>
    <option value="Trade them, we can't pick good anyways">Trade them,  we can't pick good anyways</option>

</select>
```

Then in php, you need to handle the case when the page loads, so there is no get data:

```
if(isset($_GET["uDraft"])){
    $draft= $_GET["uDraft"];
}else{
    $draft = 'DEFAULT VALUE GOES HERE';
}
echo "I want to output **$draft var** as the value they choose so it shows";
```

This could be handled with a ternary if as well:

```
$draft = isset($_GET['uDraft'])? $_GET['uDraft'] : 'DEFAULT';
```

Comment: Thank you Steve for the help.  Your answer is much more technical, but I appreciate your help.  Hopefully we will cover more of what you put so I understand it a bit better.  Thank you.